# Label last set of rows in grouped dataset with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**EDIT**: problem below given the `df.assign(Flag=1 - df.duplicated(['id', 'quarter', 'lot'], keep='last'))` method suggested below

```
 index   mkid     ordernumber quarter lotnumber1 order_xldate  Flag
441670  10176228  0108595504  2015Q2    12947-1   2015-04-09     0
441211  10176228  0108663905  2015Q2    12947-1   2015-04-29     1
450008  10176228  0108663905  2015Q2     129161   2015-04-29     1
440268  10176228  0108779992  2015Q2    12987-1   2015-05-29     0
448187  10176228  0108779992  2015Q2    12848-1   2015-05-29     1
439085  10176228  0108895691  2015Q2    12987-1   2015-06-29     1
446123  10176228  0108895691  2015Q2    12965-1   2015-06-29     1
419419  10176228  0109003405  2015Q3    12969-1   2015-07-27     1
429893  10176228  0109003405  2015Q3    12987-1   2015-07-27     1
426850  10176228  0109241988  2015Q3      13929   2015-09-15     1
384762  10176228  0109385611  2015Q4     K10127   2015-10-09     1
```

The `Flag` field is being applied to every `ordernumber` in the given quarter, *not* the **last** `ordernumber`. So, above, for `2015Q2`, `Flag` should only hit for both lines of `ordernumber 0108895691`

---

**PRIOR POST**:

I currently have a dataset of sales orders in which each `ordernumber` is divided into lots (i.e., `lot1`, `lot2`, etc.). So, there may be various rows for each `ordernumber`. Other pertinent columns are account `id` and `quarter` (i.e., 2018Q2). For each given `id` in each given `quarter`, I want to apply a flag to *all* the lots of the last order within that given quarter using Pandas / Python. Any advice?

Currently have:

```
masterDF['FLAG'] = masterDF.groupby(by=['id','quarter'],as_index=False)['ordernumber'].nth(-1)
masterDF['LAST_ORDER_OF_QUARTER'] = np.where(masterDF['FLAG'].isnull(),0,1)
```

But that only puts a 1 on just the *last* row of that id/quarter/order combination, not on *all* rows within that given order if that ordernumber appears on more than one row.

My desired output is to have a 1 on both lots of `orderB`

```
id   |   quarter   |   ordernumber   |   lot      |    Last Order of Quarter
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A    |   2018Q1    |   orderA        |   lot1     |     0
A    |   2018Q1    |   orderB        |   lot1     |     1
A    |   2018Q1    |   orderB        |   lot2     |     1
```

Instead of:

```
id   |   quarter   |   ordernumber   |   lot      |    Last Order of Quarter
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A    |   2018Q1    |   orderA        |   lot1     |     0
A    |   2018Q1    |   orderB        |   lot1     |     0
A    |   2018Q1    |   orderB        |   lot2     |     1
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Use `duplicated`

```
df.assign(Flag=1 - df.duplicated(['id', 'quarter', 'lot'], keep='last'))

  id quarter ordernumber   lot  Flag
0  A  2018Q1      orderA  lot1     0
1  A  2018Q1      orderB  lot1     1
2  A  2018Q1      orderB  lot2     1
```

---

Same thing

```
df.assign(**{'Last Order': 1 - df.duplicated(['id', 'quarter', 'lot'], keep='last')})

  id quarter ordernumber   lot  Last Order
0  A  2018Q1      orderA  lot1           0
1  A  2018Q1      orderB  lot1           1
2  A  2018Q1      orderB  lot2           1
```

Comment: Sorry: I want the Last Order flag to be 1 on both `lot1` and `lot2` of `orderB`: it appears this matches what I currently have now and only puts the 1 on the last row, not the prior row as well.

Comment: Don't think this worked: got a ``ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 57, placement implies 1`` when I put in: ``masterDF['TEMP_COL_id'] = masterDF.assign(**{'Last Order': 1 - masterDF.duplicated(['id', 'quarter', 'lot'], keep='last')})``

Comment: Assign returns a dataframe. You are trying to cram a whole dataframe into a column.

Comment: Just do masterDF = whatever I wrote

Comment: Don't think this works, it's still putting a 1 into the last row of every order, regardless of whether it's the last order in the quarter or not. So, in the above example, order A is getting a 1 in this code.

Comment: Edit your post with an example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your groupby object gives a convenient table to merge back into the main. Assign "Last Order" to 1 on that table, merge it to main, and fill the NaNs with 0.

```
new = df.groupby(['id', 'quarter']).nth(-1)
del new['lot']
new['Last Order'] = 1
df = pd.merge(df, new, how='left').fillna(0)
```

This gives:

```
    id  quarter ordernumber lot value
0   a   2018Q1  orderA  lot1    0.0
1   a   2018Q1  orderA  lot2    0.0
2   a   2018Q1  orderB  lot1    1.0
3   b   2018Q1  orderC  lot2    0.0
4   b   2018Q1  orderD  lot1    1.0
5   b   2018Q1  orderD  lot2    1.0
```

Comment: Does this work? How is this different from what I currently have? I think id ``b`` would have ``orderC`` or ``orderD``...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize separate ids would have separate orders. Clarified in edits above.

Comment: Still am getting ``ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 56, placement implies 1`` -- any advice?

Comment: Can you share a small dataframe that gives you that error? The code is working on my small dummy dataframe, but I may be missing some assumption about your df.